# Stop WooCommerce from updating user/user meta after checkout

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Customers have billing/shipping addresses saved to their account and when they checkout they are presented with the billing/shipping address fields. If they update them in the checkout and confirm their order, this also updates their addresses on their account. I understand this is the expected behaviour but not what our site requires.

I want to still show the address fields on the checkout but don't want it to update their account once it is being processed, but I also need the addresses they enter during checkout to be attached to the order meta, so the addresses on the order/order meta match those that they entered during checkout.

Is this possible? I've tried looking for hooks or how to programatically approach this but all I can find is how to add additional meta fields to an order which is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid user registration data to be updated each time an order is placed use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_customer_data', '__return_false' );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!